# How to see if my device was used at a particular time

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I'm trying to find out if my tablet was used at a particular time. It runs android 4.1. I tried to use cache.wifi but that does not seem to exist any more. It would have most likely been used on my home wifi network, but unfortunately my router doesn't have logging enabled so it looks like my only option is some sort of log that would be on the device itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Android's built-in `Battery use` info can show you the screen-on times. That should be a good indicator if someone recently touched your device.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the battery use on my device doesn't seem to stretch back far enough (at least the on screen display). Do you know if further historic data is accessible on the device (it's rooted)?

Comment: By finding files in the storage that were created or modified during a given period may help you. You can see [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/using-find-to-locate-files-created-between-certain-dates-343569/) post on how to do so. I don't know enough Linux commands to get this done and also it doesn't mean that your device was not used at this time, if the result is negative. However, if this test comes positive it is sure that the device was used during that time by some one.

Comment: I did an ls -lR / and grepped for the particular day in question. It looks like theres usually temporary files created most times you use it. In my case i couldn't find the times I was looking for but there were files for times i definately know i used it so looks like it wasn't used. I think that's the best I'm going to do. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not too far in the past, a logcat might be helpful. Unfortunately, `adb logcat` doesn't print the date/time along in a readable format; using a graphical frontend like *QtADB* would get around that. Note, however, as Android logging uses a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer), older entries might already be overwritten.

Comment: I tried this but the log rotation time is too short for my needs. Thanks anyway!